# Calling a Apex controller method using JavaScript in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, javascript, salesforce-id

Hi can anybody guide me how to call a method in controller from a VF page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apex method:

```
public PageReference getMyMethod(){
    ....
    return null;
}
```

Visualforce page action function:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!MyMethod}" name="myFunction" />
```

actionFunction works like a javascript function, so you can call it from anywhere at your page like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!something}" onchange="myFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two methods to do this :

1)Use @Remote Action Call to call the method

2)Use ACtion Function and call on the event

Here are the documentations for the same

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm

Video of demo sessions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckkChgcM9VQ

Summary :Use actionfunction if you need to maintain state between postbacks, remoteaction for stateless invocations

Comment: Use actionfunction if you need to maintain state between postbacks, remoteaction for stateless invocations.