# want to add value in list from javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting

my controller have on list of id

// list in controller

```
List<Id> ids {get;set;}
```

when i call javascript fuction i have to add id which i have passed to that function

//fuction in vfp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function listaccess(cid)
    {

        '{!ids}'.add(cid);
    }

</script>
```

this is not working

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranjit,

you can create a controller method to add/update the list and call that method from your javascript.

```
public PageReference UpdateMyList(Id myId){
   ids.add(myId);
   return null;
}
```

and you have couple of options [**Action Function or Remote Action**] in calling the controller method from your VF page / script

refer this prvious answer for more details on both the options
[Calling a Apex controller method using JavaScript in VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4910/calling-a-apex-controller-method-using-javascript-in-vf-page)