# Page Message not show in my VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I just used the below code in my application but the page message not show. What i doing wrong

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:outputpanel id="outid" >
<div id="divId"> 
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SomeList}" var="k" >
<apex:column headerValue="COl 1">
 <a href="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure?'))CallMethod('{!k.Id}');" >Del</a>
</apex:column>

etc.,
```

**Apex:**

```
public PageReference  CallMethod()
 {
try{ 
    //my insert code    
   }catch(System.DMLException e) {
apexpages.Message  msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Fake Error');
apexpages.addmessage(msg);
return Page.MyPageName;
} 
return null;
}
```

I think some render problem. Because if i am removing the try catch, i got the exception error in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was the issue. Simply Define the id for pagemesage and render that well.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an ApexPages.Message, you need to return null to refresh the current page if you want the user to see the message on the current page

Hence the `return Page.MyPageName` in the catch block should be `return null;`

If you want the message to appear on a redirected page, you need to place the message in a query string param that is read by the VF controller constructor of that redirected page which in turn recreates the `ApexPages.Message`

> UPDATE

I also noticed that you are invoking your controller's action method via a Javascript call:

```
<a href="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure?'))CallMethod('{!k.Id}');" >Del</a>
```

This will not work as Javascript can't directly invoke a controller action method. Instead, you use `apex:actionFunction` to do this.

You can see this done [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4910/2602) and [here in the SFDC doc](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) (showing how to pass a parameter)

Comment: Have you tried inserting  a record which will throw an exception and enter the   catch block?